# Python: Use specific parts of a string (that looks like a list)

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x

I have a text file (file.txt):

```
(A->[a:5,a:5,a:5,b:50,c:10,c:10])
(B->[e:120,g:50])
(C->[a:5,f:20])
```

and I want to extract and sum the values paired with 'a' (or 'b' or 'c' or ...) so that:

```
totalValue = 20 # of 'a'
#OR
totalValue = 50 # of 'b'
#OR
totalValue = 20 # of 'c'
```

Note: text file is obviously not a list, even though it looks like it.

```
myFile = open("file.txt", "r")

while True:
    theline = myFile.readline()
    if "a" in theline:     #Just used 'a' here as an example.
        for char in theline:
            ...        

myFile.close()
```

That's roughly the code I have to read the file and check each line for 'a' (for example).

Thank you.

Comment: What is `allOrders`? Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: @dkasak Irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]

myFile = open("file.txt", "r")
content = myFile.read()
totalValue = 0

all_colon_indexes = find(content,':')

for i in range(0,len(content)):
    if content[i]==':':
        if content[i-1]=='a':  #THIS IS WHERE YOU SPECIFY 'a' or 'b' or 'c', etc
            value=''
            index = i+1
            while True:
                if content[index].isdigit()==True:
                    value=value+content[index]
                    index=index+1
                else:
                    break
            _value = int(value)
            totalValue = totalValue + _value

print totalValue
```

result:

```
20
```

Comment: Result for 'b' is 50. And result for 'c' is 20.

Answer (score 0):

First, parse the couples using a regular expression which extracts them all.

Then use the nice `itertools.groupby` to gather the values using keys as the `a,b,c...` letter (first item of the regex tuple).

Finally, create tuples with variable, sum of values as integer

```
import re,itertools

with open("file.txt", "r") as myFile:

    r = re.compile("(\w+):(-?\d+)")

    for l in myFile:
        tuples = r.findall(l)
        sums = []
        for variable,values in itertools.groupby(tuples,lambda t: t[0]):
            sums.append((variable,sum(int(x[1]) for x in values)))
        print(l,sums)
```

output:

```
(A->[a:5,a:5,a:5,b:50,c:10,c:10]) [('a', 15), ('b', 50), ('c', 20)]
(B->[e:120,g:50]) [('e', 120), ('g', 50)]
(C->[a:5,f:20]) [('a', 5), ('f', 20)]
```

If you want the total sum for all lines, small changes. First accumulate all tuples in a list (source line is not important), then apply `groupby` on the sorted list (or grouping won't work properly)

```
import re,itertools

with open("file.txt", "r") as myFile:

  r = re.compile("(\w+):(-?\d+)")

  tuples = []
  for l in myFile:
      tuples += r.findall(l)

  sums = []
  for variable,values in itertools.groupby(sorted(tuples),lambda t: t[0]):
      sums.append((variable,sum(int(x[1]) for x in values)))
  print(sums)
```

result:

```
[('a', 20), ('b', 50), ('c', 20), ('e', 120), ('f', 20), ('g', 50)]
```

Comment: Now you have a two separated values for 'a' though.
Any way to add them together into one value?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the file using regular expressions:

- `\w` stands for a word character
- `\d` stands for a digit
- `+` specifies that you want to match one or more of the preceding match groups
- `?` specifies that you want to match zero or one of the preceding match groups (to account for a minus character)
- parentheses specify that what is matched inside them should be extracted as a group of characters so we have two groups (one for the letter, one for the number)

Then use a `defaultdict` to hold the name -> sum mapping. A `defaultdict` is like an ordinary `dict`, but when the key is missing, it creates it with a default value obtained by calling the callable you supplied when creating it. In this case this is `int` which returns `0` when called.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

value_pattern = re.compile("(\w+):(-?\d+)")
totals = defaultdict(int)

with open("file.txt", "r") as myFile:
    for line in myFile.readlines():
        values = value_pattern.findall(line)
        for name, value in values:
            totals[name] += int(value)

        print(totals.items())
        totals.clear()
```

This gives

```
dict_items([('c', 20), ('a', 15), ('b', 50)])
dict_items([('g', 50), ('e', 120)])
dict_items([('f', 20), ('a', 5)])
```

when run on your file.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest a somehow more compact solution that sums up every "key" in the text file and outputs a dictionary:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

with open('a.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()

tups = re.findall(r'(\w+):(\d+)', lines)
print(tups)
# tups is a list of tuples in the form (key, value), ie [('a': '5'), ...]

sums = defaultdict(int)
for tup in tups:
    sums[tup[0]] += int(tup[1])

print(sums)
```

Will output:

```
[('a', '5'), ('a', '5'), ('a', '5'), ('b', '50'), ('c', '10'), ('c', '10'), ('e', '120'), ('g', '50'), ('a', '5'), ('f', '20')]
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'f': 20, 'b': 50, 'e': 120, 'a': 20, 'c': 20, 'g': 50})
```

And more specifically:

```
print(sums['a'])
>> 20
print(sums['b'])
>> 50
```

Answer (score 0):

No intention on stepping on Jean-Francois's toes :-) - I would suggest using *Counter* for count.

```
import collections
with open("file.txt", "r") as myFile:

    r = re.compile("(\w+):(-?\d+)")
    res = collections.Counter()
    for l in myFile:
        for key, cnt in r.findall(l):
            res.update({key: int(cnt)})
```

result: `res` is now:

```
Counter({'e': 120, 'b': 50, 'g': 50, 'c': 20, 'f': 20, 'a': 20})
```

you can access it like a dictionary: ex:

```
res["a"] => 20
```

Comment: do I feel offended ? :) I fixed & completed your answer even (was missing `()` when creating the counter.

Comment: funny how the answers with a score > 0 got downvoted. Is that to hide the mediocrity of the accepted answer ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, as my former management used to claim - the code is too high-level :-)

Comment: for what it's worth I would have accepted _your_ answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I appreciate the sentiment. But obviously it's ways out of OP's comfort zone.